# Set $httpProvider common headers outside of config() method of AngularJS modules

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, config

How can I do this:

`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]='123';`

From elsewhere than the module `config()` method but still have it act globally for all requests made for that module (app-wide).?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very simple, you can just set it on the `$http` object after the config() phase at any time:

`$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]='123';`